# Question on the semantic role of objects licensed by verbs indicating prevention

Tags: semantics

It goes without saying that the title of this question is perhaps rather prolix, so allow me to illustrate what I mean.

Consider the below sentence.

> The man's heroic actions prevented the innocent woman's death.

The focus of this question extends also to other preventative verbs, such as 'avoid', 'stop', etc., but only in their transitive senses. All of these verbs (in their transitive senses) license objects with the same (or a very similar) semantic role.

However, to my mind it is not clear what this semantic role is. It seems to be the negative counterpart of the semantic role of factitive theme: the verbs in 'prevent', 'stop', etc. *stop* something's coming into existence, while factitive verbs cause something to come into existence (e.g. in the sentence *He made a chair*, the chair comes into existence by virtue of his making it).

Is there a name for the semantic role of the objects licensed by these preventative verbs?

Comment: +1 Whilst this is a perfectly good question for this site, you may get a better answer if you post it on Linguistics SE!